# How do I size a ReorderableListView to the height of all the children

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to size the ReorderableListView (because otherwise it throws an error) and I'm trying to make it have the same size as the children of the reorderable list view.

Here's the code so far:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: <Widget>[
      reorderableList(context),
    ],
  );
}

Widget reorderableList(BuildContext context) {
return Align(
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
      minHeight: 0,
    ),
    //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
    child: ReorderableListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (newIndex > oldIndex) newIndex -= 1;
          widget.controller.chosenImages.insert(
              newIndex, widget.controller.chosenImages.removeAt(oldIndex));
        });
        widget.controller.onReorder(context);
      },
      children: widget.controller.chosenImages.map((image) {
        return reorderableListTile(context, image, Key(image.name));
      }).toList(growable: true),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

The reorderableListTile widget does have a set height of 55. Also, here's an image of what this looks like: [image: Current layout of widgets]

As you can see, I want the red area to be only as big as the list tiles, but it currently set itself at the maxHeight instead.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: It seems to me that you do not need the ListView, remove it and use only the reorderableList instead.

Comment: I'm using the listview in case the screen size is too small and it overflows. Unless you know a better way to deal with this?